# Java jList1.getSelectedValue() returns an Object. I need a String from the selected list item.

Tags: java, string, swing, object, jlist

I'm a second year Java student, and I'm learning various things on my own time. One of these is `JList`.

```
jList1.getSelectedValue();
```

The above code returns an `Object`, not a `String`. I need a `String` of the selected list item. `Adding/removing` models from the listbox is not a problem. The list's contents are constantly changing (with the model), so using `.getSelectedIndex()` as a work-around is undesirable.

Help?

**EDIT:** I do have a listener working for the `jList`, I just need this one problem solved.

Comment: Just use a cast... String val = (String)jList1.getSelectedValue();

Comment: @Quirliom why not adding this as an answer, so it can be selected as chosen answer by user?

Answer (score 2):

Just use a cast, or the toString method as Andrew mentioned in his comment:

```
String val = (String)jList1.getSelectedValue();
```

or:

```
String val = jList1.getSelectedValue().toString();
```

Comment: No need for casting if JList contains ListModel with string objects.

Comment: `jList1.getSelectedValue().toString()` would avoid the cast.

Answer (score 1):

Method `getSelectedValue()` from class [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) returns selected object which you've added in `ListModel`. Either it can be a String,Integer or any other Object.

If you generate a JList like this

```
String[] data = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};
JList myJList = new JList(data);
```

select method `myJList.getSelectedValue();` obviously return a string.

If you add your own objects like `Student` or `Department`, you get the same object when selection and when you try to print it the hashCode reference of the object would be printed unless you overwrite `toString()` method in your own class.

Comment: The getSelectedValue() method still returns an Object...  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValue()

Comment: @Quirliom yes the object which is added in ListModel not string.

Comment: But you would not be able to use any String methods on the returned value without a toString() or cast.

Comment: @Quirliom `toString()` method returns String representation of the object which added in ListModel and you will get class cast exception when trying to cast with `String` unless you have JList<String>.

Comment: @Quirliom *But you would not be able to use any String methods on the returned value without a toString() or cast* - Yes of course. Generics doesn't require casting.

Answer (score 0):

You could either cast the returned Object to String, given you already filler the list with String values. Alternatively you could deal with the list through the ListModel, but either using the DefaultListModel (Also handles data as Objects) or implementing your own ListModel to provide what ever functionality you need such as restricting the list data types to String.

Answer (score 0):

I used `.toString()` or casting to string but I received the address of the selection, not the the values. So I tried this code, and it did work:

```
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
        String a[] = new String[20];// To save the selections
        int i = 0, j = 0;

            // Get the selected values.
            Object[] selections = array2List.getSelectedValues();

        // To save the selections in array
        for(Object selections : sugCoursesList.getSelectedValues())
        {
            for(String t : array2)
            {
                if (selections == t)
                {
                    a[i] = t;
                    i++;
                    System.out.println(selections);     
                }   
            }
        }

        for(String s: a)
            System.out.println("a " + s);
  }
```

I have compared the array that was in the list to check if it is selected if yes save it in array a.